# Creating a report using as an data set an Object and loading through a DataTable

Tags: c#, reportviewer

I'm having trouble creating a report using report viewer.

I'm having trouble creating a report using the report viewer. I want to load it through a DataTable and use a class as dataset

```
 public  class ViewDoenca
    {
        // Classe
        private int _codigo { get; set; }
        private string _descricao { get; set; }
        private int _status { get; set; }
        private string _observacao { get; set; }

        public int codigo
        {
            get { return _codigo; }
            set { _codigo = value; }
        }

        public string descricao
        {
            get { return _descricao; }
            set { _descricao = value; }
        }

        public int status
        {
            get { return _status; }
            set { _status = value; }
        }

        public string observacao
        {
            get { return _observacao; }
            set { _observacao = value; }
        }
    }
```

and I have an .xaml file that is the screen where I display the reports

```
 public void ExibeReport(DataTable dt, string rel, string Titulo, string Filtro)
        {
            try
            {
                this._reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

                ReportDataSource DTSource = new ReportDataSource("Data", dt);


                this._reportViewer.SetDisplayMode(Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.DisplayMode.PrintLayout);
                this._reportViewer.ZoomMode = Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ZoomMode.Percent;
                this._reportViewer.ZoomPercent = 100;
                this._reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(DTSource);

                _reportViewer.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = "SistemaNutricao.Relatorios." + rel;

                this._reportViewer.RefreshReport();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Ocorreu um erro ao tentar gerar o relatório, verifique se sua versão do Report Viewer está instalada e atualizada.");
            }
        }


        private void _reportViewer_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                this._reportViewer.RefreshReport();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Erro ao tenta gerar relatorio! Faça download do reportviewer");
            }
        }
```

**dt** = DataTable where I am passing the data, containing 4 columns (code, description, status and observation)
**rel** = name of the report I want to use in this case is "RelDoencas.rdlc"
**titulo** and **filtro** are some parameters but I'm not using

[image: error displayed while generating report]

[image: creating report]

Comment: Crystal Reports is a lot friendlier than ReportViewer if you have that option.

Comment: To use the crystal I would have to install it on my client machine and this could not occur